# bookdown multi-column: html + pdf combo: pandoc fenced div syntax?

Tags: css, r, latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I'm using bookdown to build html and pdf books with a chapter that has side-by-side paragraphs that are formatted differently. I've added such a paragraph to the bookdown "Minimal Book Example" and I don't understand the syntax of the "fenced div" as described https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/multi-column.html .

This recipe suggests something like:

```
:::: {.cols data-latex=""}

::: {.col .italic-box data-latex="{0.45\textwidth}" }

text for left column

:::

::: {.col .space-box data-latex="{0.05\textwidth}"}
\ 
<!-- an empty Div (with a white space), serving as
a column separator -->
:::

::: {.col data-latex="{0.45\textwidth}"}

text for right column

:::
::::
```

**problem**: the text paragraphs are built side-by-side for both html and pdf, but they are not picking up the peculiar formatting requirements that I've tried to specify via css and tex.

**question**: does the string {.col .italic-box data-latex="{0.45\textwidth}" } prevent me from adding more detail in the css and tex config files?

I assume the string means that the paragraph that follows is to be formatted per the css classes ".col" and ".italic-box" (which are in my columns.css) and those same two labels (without the leading '.') are 'environment' labels in the tex configuration file.

index.Rmd yaml has:

```
output: 
    html_document: 
       css: ["./css/columns.css", "./css/style.css"]
    bookdown::pdf_book: 
      keep_tex: true
      includes:
        in_header:  ["./tex/preamble.tex", "./tex/columns.tex"]
```

columns.css has

```
.cols {
  display: flex;
}
.source-col {
  font-style: italic;
}
.italic-box {
  font-style: italic  !important;
  background-color: #d9d9d9  !important;
  border-style: solid  !important;
  width: 45% !important;
}
.space-box {
  width: 5% !important;
}
```

tex.columns has

```
\newenvironment{cols}[1][]{}{}

\newenvironment{col}[1]{\begin{minipage}{#1}\ignorespaces}{%
\end{minipage}
\ifhmode\unskip\fi
\aftergroup\useignorespacesandallpars}

\def\useignorespacesandallpars#1\ignorespaces\fi{%
#1\fi\ignorespacesandallpars}

\makeatletter
\def\ignorespacesandallpars{%
  \@ifnextchar\par
    {\expandafter\ignorespacesandallpars\@gobble}%
    {}%
}
\makeatother


\setlength{\fboxsep}{.8em}

\newenvironment{italic-box}{
  \textwidth{0.45}
  \definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0, 0, 0}  % black
  \color{white}
  \begin{shaded}\itshape}
 {\end{shaded}}
```

preamble.tex has

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=8pt plus 2pt minus 4pt
  \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
\makeatother
```

reproducible code: see 02-literature.Rmd  https://github.com/cordphelps/simpleBookdown

I'm running RStudio Version 1.4.1725
macOS Big Sur version 11.5

Comment: I'm unsure how your desired output in your mind looks like, but you can nest the boxes you defined (i.e. `{.italic-box}` and `{.space-box}`) into the Pandoc's predefined environment `{.col data-latex="..."}` (See also [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#additional-columns-attributes-in-beamer) and [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-fenced_divs) to know more about `fenced_divs`). Also, you may be able to set the column width by `%` like `{.col width="45%"}`; by that notation, you can avoid the latex-specific `{0.45\textwidth}` for the width setting.